# Disable intellisense in 1.17

Tags: visual-studio-code

With today's VScode update 1.17, IntelliSense for import paths is turned on automatically. However, I've been using extensions to use this feature before.

Is there a way to turn off VScode's IntelliSense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using javascript, for example:

```
"[javascript]": {
      "editor.quickSuggestions": false
}
```

It turns off all intellisense for .js files.  If you are using a different language, you could do the same. See the "language specific configuration settings..." after <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and choose your language.  It will automatically create an empty ruleset in your settings.json file and you could add the editor.quickSuggestions rule above to it.

Also look at

> // Enables pop-up that shows parameter documentation and type
>   information as you type   "editor.parameterHints": true,

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried what You said, nothing helped. I ended up removing extensions